# If string is preceded by comma insert a new line Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have data in below format in a file.

```
abc : 123456 ,abc : 98766543,xyz : ABC DEF IJK,OPR : No
abc : 456363738,xyz :MNORET ,OPR : YES
abc : 66898965 ,abc : ABC9543,xyz : qwert,OPR : Yes
```

If abc : is preceded by comma then insert a new line. So that output appears in below format .

```
abc : 123456 ,
abc : 98766543,xyz : ABC DEF IJK,OPR : No
abc : 456363738,xyz :MNORET ,OPR : YES
abc : 66898965 ,
abc : ABC9543,xyz : qwert,OPR : Yes
```

I tried using sed to replace it but it is not working .
 `sed  -e 's/,abc ://\n abc :/g' 1.txt`

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/(,)(abc :)/\1\n\2/g' file
```

Output:

```
abc : 123456 ,
abc : 98766543,xyz : ABC DEF IJK,OPR : No
abc : 456363738,xyz :MNORET ,OPR : YES
abc : 66898965 ,
abc : ABC9543,xyz : qwert,OPR : Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` solution may also help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/,abc :/,",\n&");sub(",\n,",",\n")} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
abc : 123456 ,
abc : 98766543,xyz : ABC DEF IJK,OPR : No
abc : 456363738,xyz :MNORET ,OPR : YES
abc : 66898965 ,
abc : ABC9543,xyz : qwert,OPR : Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `awk`, `gsub()` function replace `,abc` with `,\nabc`

   ```
   $ awk '{gsub(/,abc/,",\nabc")}1' infile
   ```
2. Using **GNU awk** `gensub()` function

   ```
   $ awk '{print gensub(/(,)(abc)/,"\\1\n\\2","")}' infile
   ```

Test Results:

**Input:**

```
$ cat infile
abc : 123456 ,abc : 98766543,xyz : ABC DEF IJK,OPR : No
abc : 456363738,xyz :MNORET ,OPR : YES
abc : 66898965 ,abc : ABC9543,xyz : qwert,OPR : Yes
```

**Using awk**

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,abc/,",\nabc")}1' infile
abc : 123456 ,
abc : 98766543,xyz : ABC DEF IJK,OPR : No
abc : 456363738,xyz :MNORET ,OPR : YES
abc : 66898965 ,
abc : ABC9543,xyz : qwert,OPR : Yes
```

**Using GNU awk**

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(,)(abc)/,"\\1\n\\2","")}' infile
abc : 123456 ,
abc : 98766543,xyz : ABC DEF IJK,OPR : No
abc : 456363738,xyz :MNORET ,OPR : YES
abc : 66898965 ,
abc : ABC9543,xyz : qwert,OPR : Yes
```